# How to fix Error In MongoDB Nodejs: RangeError: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792. Received 17825794

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've encountered this bug when adding data to the MongoDB database. When my variable 'i' reaches , the issue occurs. (i = 0 -> 60000)[image: ERROR HERE]

```
export const addQuestion = async () => {
    const data = await CrawlDicamonQuestion.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const questionObj = data[i];
        console.log({ i });
        const book = await Book.findOne({ slug: questionObj.slugBook });
        if (!book) throw new HttpException(400, "Not found book!");
        const subject = await Subject.findById(book.subject);
        if (!subject) throw new HttpException(400, "Not found subject!");
        const grade = Number(subject.subject.slice(-2)).toString();

        // console.log({ book, subject });

        const topic = await Topic.findOne({ topic: questionObj.topic, book: book._id });
        // console.log({ topic });

        if (!topic) throw new HttpException(400, "Not found topic!");
        const lesson = await Lesson.findOne({ lesson: questionObj.lesson, book: book._id, topic: topic._id });
        if (!lesson) throw new HttpException(400, "Not found lesson!");

        const user = await User.findOne({ username: "modhoibai" });
        if (!user) throw new HttpException(400, "Not found user admin!");

        let isConfirm: boolean;
        const contentHtml = questionObj.htmlContent;
        // if (contentHtml.includes('<figure class="image')) {
        if (contentHtml.includes("<img")) {
            isConfirm = false;
        } else {
            isConfirm = true;
        }

        const createdQuestion = await Question.create({
            isFromAdmin: true,
            bookInSystem: book._id,
            user: user._id,
            subject: book.subject,
            grade: grade,
            score: 0,
            topic: topic._id,
            lesson: lesson._id,
            contentHtml: questionObj.htmlContent,
            page: questionObj.page,
            isConfirm: isConfirm
        });

        // auto follow
        await FollowQuestion.create({
            question: createdQuestion._id,
            user: []
        });
    }
};
```

[image: This is the state of the database when the error occurs][![DB.find()],(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8mOj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8mOj.png)

If I remove the 'Question.create()' function, the error disappears. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `questions` in the same database?   ... on the same MongoDB server?

Comment: Yes, there is only one database

Comment: If you use [`mongoose.set('bufferCommands', false);`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering), is there any change?

Comment: I realized a bug in Middleware when creating a new document, it's "HTML content" field.
My bug creates an error field that includes more than 50.000.000 characters and can't save.
Thank you for your support!